# Show $\inf(A) = \inf(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

I'm trying to show $\inf(A) = \inf(B)$, for $B$ contained in $A$ and $a+m\in B$, for all $a\in A$ and $m>0$.

I have shown that $\inf(A)\leq\inf(B)$, but I'm having a hard time showing that the $\inf(B)\leq \inf(A)$. So, I have shown that the greatest lower bound of $A$ will be the greatest lower bound of $B$, but I am having a hard time showing that the greatest lower bound of $B$ is also the greatest lower bound of $A$.

So, I've shown that $\inf(A)\leq\inf(B)$ by showing that $a\leq b$, but I can't seem to show $b\leq a$. Do I even need to show $b\leq a$ to prove $\inf(B) \leq \inf(A)$?

Here's what I tried and failed at :

$\ InfB\leq\ b = a+m$ for all $a∈A$.

So, $\ InfB\leq\ a+m =b$ for all $a∈A$.

So, $\ InfB\leq\ b-m = a$ for all $b∈B,a∈A$. (This part seems wrong from here an moving on)

So, $\ InfB\leq\ a$.

I'm trying to do a direct proof here, so is there a way to do this without doing a proof by contradiction?

Comment: What is “the lower bound of $A$”?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I just set the lower bound of $A$ as some $x$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I've been at this problem for a few hours now, is my approach wrong?

Comment: No set has only one lower bound. Therefore, it makes no sense to mention “the lower bound of $A$”.

Comment: I've shown that $Inf(A)≤Inf(B)$ by showing that $a≤b$, but I can't seem to show $b≤a$. Do I even need to show $b≤a$ to prove $infB≤infA$?

Comment: @OliverHouse I assume you mean *greatest lower bound* here

Comment: @Lorago Oops! Yes, of course :)

Comment: Based on what I did up there, is there a way to continue directly with inequalities like that? Or a way to fix what I might be doing wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

Let's rephrase the problem slightly:

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that are bounded below. (This ensures that the infima $\text{inf}(A)$ and $\text{inf}(B)$ are well-defined real numbers.) Suppose that for each $a\in A$ and $m>0$, we have that $a+m\in B$. You are trying to prove that $\text{inf}(A)=\text{inf}(B)$ and have already done half of the proof by showing that $\text{inf}(A)\leq\text{inf}(B)$. All that remains is to show that $\text{inf}(A)\geq\text{inf}(B)$, which we prove by contradiction below:

*Proof*: Suppose that $\text{inf}(A)<\text{inf}(B)$. By the definition of the infimum, there exists $a\in A$ with $a<\text{inf}(B)$. Then for each $m\in\mathbb{R}$ with $0<m<\text{inf}(B)-a$, we have that $a+m\in B$, and since $\text{inf}(B)$ is (by definition) a lower bound for $B$, we have that $$a+m\geq\text{inf}(B)\implies m\geq\text{inf}(B)-a,$$ a clear contradiction. and we are done.

Comment: how did you get $m:=1/2(inf(B)−a)$ ? Sorry, I'm a bit lost in the proof

Comment: also, is there a way to do a direct proof  instead to show that $infA=infB$

Comment: Are you familiar with the symbol $:=$? It means that you are defining the left hand side to be equal to the right hand side. I am basically saying 'Let $m=...$' It depends what you mean by 'direct', but I think my proof is what most people would go for

Comment: why do we define $m$ that way? Like, how did you know to define it like that? I'm trying to figure out the proof on my own too, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to define  $m$ that way

Comment: I just thought of a number that is positive and sufficiently small to give a contradiction, and this was the obvious choice

Comment: Is there a way to not use contradiction and just do a direct proof?

Comment: Possibly, but my above proof is I think the most natural choice

Comment: Okay thanks so much!! I've figured out the steps so far, but I'm still a bit stuck on defining $m$. I can't seem to derive it myself, and I'm having a hard time seeing it as the obvious choice

Comment: @eddie My proof works for any $m$ with $0<m<\text{inf}(B)-a$, with $\frac{1}{2}(\text{inf}(B)-a)$ being the midpoint of this interval. It can be done without explicitly mentioning $m$, but I thought it might be easier to understand if I did.